# laravel 4 package controller class not found

Tags: laravel, package, controllers

I have a workbench package named jumper. I have three controllers 
 -src
    --controllers
      -- dashboard
      -- nide
      -- users

I have already registered service provider for my package. There I can access two controller Auth and Nide where as I have not being able to access the Users class.

my routs are as follows :

```
// 1. dash package routes

Route::get('/dash', 'Jumper\Dash\Dashboard@index');
Route::controller('dash', 'Jumper\Dash\Dashboard');

// 2. auth/Users routes
Route::controller('users', 'Jumper\Dash\Users');
Route::get('/users', 'Jumper\Dash\Users@tests');
```

I have already run 
  -> artisan dump-autoload command 
  -> composer update

Problem is while accessing /users or running dump-autoload command it gives me

ReflectionException
Class Jumper\Dash\Users does not exist

## Note :

I have already defined the same jumper/dash as name space same as for other controller

Can Suggestions ???

Regards

Comment: run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: I have already done that but not working. 

But I have found the bug. dump-autoload was not working properly in my copy of laravel 4.

My new contorller was not being auto registered in 
vendor/package/src/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap. SO I have manually register it and it is working now.

Any wayz thank you for reply

Comment: one point. when you manuelly update the composer file, make sure it the parent folder is included in composer.json.... or else you will lose that entry.... with one file it is easier but for multiple file, you may lose track....

Comment: @NiroseMaharjan have you find the fix for it? It used to register automatically for me, but now I'm adding it manually to autoload_classmap

Comment: @meWantToLearn Sorry for the late reply..I guess you have already find the solution. Still here is my reply. It was my mistake. I should have run composer dump-autoload from package base where composer is stored not for project base. 
For example 
 Workbench/jumper/dash
"Composer dump-autoload " should be run from "dash" folder, it will re-write the auto-load-class and every thing will work fine.

Cheers